# I suffered memory loss. I forgot where the download kernel would be placed into

Tags: raspbian, kernel

I'm sorry the question is kind of lame. I was ill for a few weeks and currently keep forgetting few important things.

I've downloaded `Raspbian (Jessie)` kernel based on instructions on RPi's [Kernel Building](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md) page.

I used the same command written in there

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
```

I completely forgot in what directory the downloaded kernel would be placed into. Can someone please remind me where would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clone a git repo (and don't specify a directory name) it is placed in the current working directory, in a folder named after the repository name. So in your case it will be in the directory linux a subdirectory of the directory you were in when you cloned the repo.

Since I don't know what directory you were using at the time, you can search for the linux directory with the following:

```
sudo find / -name "linux"
```

Comment: Thank you. I followed the guide in RPi homepage step-by-step and I didn't  specify any directory name. I've found the dir using `find` but I actually used single quote. :)